# Different Font for different button states

Tags: silverlight, togglebutton, font-family

I am using a Toggle button control in Silverlight. Please tell how can i use a different font family for its Checked and Unchecked states. I have tried editing Toggle button template using Expression Blend but could not make it work. Please help.

Thanks,
Omer Javed

Answer (score 0):

You can use a converter and bind the FontFamily property of the TextBlock inside the Button to the IsChecked state of the button.

```
<ToggleButton
    x:Name="tb">
    <ToggleButton.Resources>
        <converters:BooleanToFontFamily
            x:Key="BooleanToFontFamily" />
    </ToggleButton.Resources>
    <TextBlock
        FontFamily="{Binding IsChecked, ElementName='tb', Converter={StaticResource BooleanToFontFamily}, ConverterParameter='Segoe WP Semibold,Segoe WP SemiLight'}"
        Text="Some Text" />
</ToggleButton>
```

And the converter in C# would look rouguhly like this:

```
public class BooleanToFontFamily : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(
        object value,
        Type targetType,
        object parameter,
        CultureInfo culture)
    {
        var b = (bool)value;
        var families = ((string)parameter).Split(',');
        return new FontFamily(b ? families[1] : families[0]);
    }

    public object ConvertBack(
        object value,
        Type targetType,
        object parameter,
        CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotSupportedException();
    }
}
```

Though personally - I would keep trying to get that template to work - probably something to do with the VisualStateManager handling the transition to "Checked" state.

Answer (score 0):

The easist way would be to use a built-in behaivor `ChangePropertyAction`. Since you have mentioned that you have Expression Blend installed, just go to the Asset Panel and type in 'ChangePropertyAction', then drag and drop this behavior on top of your `ToggleButton`.

After that you just need to specify after **which event** fires you want to change **what**. For more information regarding how to use this behavior, please see [this post](http://www.kirupa.com/blend_silverlight/changePropertyAction.htm).

**Some example code**

```
    <ToggleButton Content="ToggleButton" FontFamily="Arial" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
        <i:Interaction.Triggers>
            <i:EventTrigger EventName="Checked">
                <ei:ChangePropertyAction PropertyName="FontFamily">
                    <ei:ChangePropertyAction.Value>
                        <FontFamily>Arial Black</FontFamily>
                    </ei:ChangePropertyAction.Value>
                </ei:ChangePropertyAction>
            </i:EventTrigger>
            <i:EventTrigger EventName="Unchecked">
                <ei:ChangePropertyAction PropertyName="FontFamily">
                    <ei:ChangePropertyAction.Value>
                        <FontFamily>Arial</FontFamily>
                    </ei:ChangePropertyAction.Value>
                </ei:ChangePropertyAction>
            </i:EventTrigger>
        </i:Interaction.Triggers>
    </ToggleButton>
```